# How can I locate the header + object file of cksum in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, c++, gcc, checksum, c

I'm trying to locate the header + object file of cksum in Mac OS X, but with no lack. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the program `/usr/bin/cksum` is available [on Apple's Open Source web site](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-188/cksum/cksum.c), which you could have found by googling for `cksum.c`.

---

If you're looking for the functions this program uses, it's a good idea to start there.

Copies of these header files are in `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/usr/include`, if you have the Mac OS X Developer Tools installed.